# CloudFormation nested stacks outputs limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

**Facts:**

- CloudFormation Outputs limit its [60](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) per template.
- I have 90 resources to export so I created the following structure:

  - `parent_stack.template` (contains the below nested stacks)
  - `stack01.template` (contains 45 resources and its outputs)
  - `stack02.template` (contains 45 resources and its outputs)

**My issue:**

I need to export those 90 resources but I can't export them in `parent_stack.template` because of the limit.

I can export them in their respective `stack01.template` and `stack02.template` but since they are nested when CloudFormation creates them it adds a random alphanumeric string like `Stack01-1B0HKOV4YRD6A` so I can't actually use the logical name to import from the nested stacks anywhere but in the parent.

I would really appreciate any help here.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

Launched in October 2020: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/

Maximum number of outputs that you can declare in your AWS CloudFormation template: 200

Answer (score -1):

You can reference nested output variables. Look at this draft example, this would be like a main cloud formation script:

```
Description: >
    Some desc

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:

  MyStackA:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: "mystackA.yml"
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: "myprojectA"

  MyStackB:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: "mystackB.yml"
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: "myprojectB"

  MyStackC:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: "mystackC.yml"
      Parameters:
        ProjectName: "myprojectC"
        OutputFromMyStackA: !GetAtt MyStackA.Outputs.myoutputA
        OutputFromMyStackB: !GetAtt MyStackB.Outputs.myoutputB
```

MyStackC consumes params from MyStackA and MyStackB. MyStackC script will need a parameters section:

```
Parameters:

  OutputFromMyStackA:
    Description: param from stack a
    Type: String

  OutputFromMyStackB:
    Description: param from stack b
    Type: String
```

StackA and StackB need to output their own stuff too

```
Outputs:

  myoutputA:
    Description: the myoutputA
    Value: !Ref SomeStackAResource   ====> this references something inside the script for StackA
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know we can reference outputs from nested stacks the issue is when I need to output more than 60 in the parent stack.